# Windows 8.1 memory leak which is invisible in process monitor and poolmon

Tags: windows, memory, windows-8.1, memory-leaks

After trying around for days, googling about everything and trying a lot I am left clueless.

I have a Razer 2013 Blade Pro with 8GB ram.
I have 30 GB allocated for additional virtual ram.

My system eats ram, after a day I have to reboot.
Task manager always shows 7.6-7.8GB of 8GB used (after a while)
It shows 10+GB committed after half a day.
Paged and non paged pool are less than a GB.
cached is less than a GB
Processes combined are less than a GB.

Normally 'poolmon' shows that something else like a driver is using the memory.
However, in my case poolmon shows no extra usage of anything.
Right now 12GB of disk space and 8GB of real memory are in use and nothing is using it.

So essentially my question is this:
If neither the task manager nor poolmon shows memory losses or usages, what else can I try to find out WHAT is using up 20GB of memory ?

Poolmon -b:

```
     Memory: 8304828K Avail:  357404K  PageFlts:749759184   InRam Krnl:31464K P:248372K
 Commit:12798116K Limit:32880828K Peak:12958348K            Pool N:168816K P:303892K
 System pool information
 Tag  Type     Allocs            Frees            Diff       Bytes                  Per Alloc

 CM31 Paged     76680 (   0)     49859 (   0)    26821   122609664 (          0)        4571
 wcdl Nonp         43 (   0)         0 (   0)       43    32427744 (          0)      754133
 MmSt Paged    997690 (   0)    989424 (   0)     8266    28019248 (          0)        3389
 rzud Nonp     109134 (   0)     46163 (   0)    62971    15651296 (          0)         248
 CM25 Paged      3295 (   0)         0 (   0)     3295    14479360 (          0)        4394
 MmRe Paged     21218 (   0)     19623 (   0)     1595    14009152 (          0)        8783
 Toke Paged  12315343 (   0)  12310825 (   0)     4518     8803808 (          0)        1948
 ConT Nonp       1585 (   0)      1212 (   0)      373     6365184 (          0)       17064
 BGIK Paged         1 (   0)         0 (   0)        1     6221824 (          0)     6221824
 Thre Nonp     449909 (   0)    447365 (   0)     2544     5244384 (          0)        2061
 Ntff Paged    582079 (   0)    578052 (   0)     4027     5218992 (          0)        1296
 CM16 Paged      9083 (   0)      8010 (   0)     1073     4685824 (          0)        4367
 Irp  Nonp   75321006 (   0)  75307341 (   0)    13665     4645936 (          0)         339
 XENO Nonp        594 (   0)       399 (   0)      195     4317616 (          0)       22141
 ViMm Paged   1873388 (   0)   1862026 (   0)    11362     4057360 (          0)         357
 File Nonp   59994297 (   0)  59983847 (   0)    10450     3492864 (          0)         334
```

The only unusual thing I see here is "pageflts" which is high, after first second of poolmon it drops to 50k per update.
I guess that indicates something, maybe just that something is trying to get memory in an insane rate.

Update:
I did not play on it,  did not change resolution.
[image]

Update: Rammap images with photoshop loaded (5GB in process memory):
[image]
[image]
Rammap images with photoshop stopped (memory still shows to be full):
[image]

Also strange, aside from 18GB commited memory that are not shown, rammap shows 5 GB in processes which is also not the case.

P.S. I did a malwarebytes rootkit scan without anything.
That's the only thing I can think about, a major bug in the windows OS regarding memory usage or a kernel rootkit.

Comment: Did you ever confirm what the problem was, if any?

Comment: Nope, I eventually reinstalled and problems were gone.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [virtual Memory DirectX issue](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=1225941) in Windows 8 which is caused when you run Application/Games in a different resolution compared to the Desktop resolution and in full screen.

You should see such a sawtooth graph in Process Explorer:

[image]

Microsoft will release a fix for this bug in the August 2014 Update Rollup. So you have to wait 1 more month until this gets fixed or play/run apps always with the native resolution.

Comment: I do not think that's the case.
The memory is permanently up, there is no falling at any time with exception of a 100mb +-.
Also I did not play at all, resolution did not change either.

Comment: post some pictures of RAMMap (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx) when you have the high memory issue

Comment: I posted rammap pictures.

Comment: also look in Process Explorer (Systeminformation window) if you have this strange grow/rise. What I see looks like this known DX Bug

Comment: I made a ramma with photoshop loaded (5GB usage) and after I closed it again.
The commited bytes change by 5GB.
The physical memory was first occupied by photoshop, after closing it is occupied by 'unknown' again.

I can tell you for sure I have no rises or falls at all, it grows to the physical limit and then permanently stays on that.
Now the commited memory on SSD grows until it is full and I have to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you're saying "5 GB in procs which is not the case". Just from the procs you've shown (second screen snap) I see 3.1 GB. And the private working set of a process is not its only use of RAM (the rest is for sharable pages). It looks to me as if you simply are running a large number of memory-hungry things at one time; the cure is to run fewer of them, or do less with them so they don't need as much RAM, or else add more RAM.

Your high page fault rate also points in that direction.

Committed is not shown on that table because it isn't "RAM", and RAMmap is all about accounting for RAM usage. Committed memory is one type of virtual address space (the other types, in user space anyway, are "mapped" and "free"). Some of it for each proc is in the "Private" column, the rest in the pagefile.

One thing that does look odd is that you report 8 GB RAM + "30 GB allocated for additional virtual ram", by which I guess you mean pagefile (otherwise I don't know what you mean). That should result in a commit limit of 38GB, but you are only showing 31.4 GB. Fixing this will not solve your problem, though, as you are not even close to running out of commit.

Comment: The memory runs out without processes eating it.
No available task manager or tool I found was able to visualize the usage.
Currently I added a second SSD and give it 100 GB of virtual memory. So I don't have to reboot all the time.

Comment: What are you talking about? _The images you've posted show processes using it!_ Your first instance of absomethingstudio.exe shows 459,xxx KB - that is almost half of a GB. Add them up. As I said before, just the ones you've shown in your screen cap total to about 3.1 GB, and most systems have over a hundred processes...  Also as I said before, you were nowhere near running out of commit limit, so adding more pagefile space (what you are calling "100 GB of virtual memory") won't help. You need more RAM.

Comment: Yea I posted a snapshot with an application running and the list you see is almost complete and it is sorted by total usage.
The last listed process is already at 70MB mem usage.

I would not have made this question if I had not made sure that this is NOT a process problem. even with all processes stopped and only the most essential background running the memory was nearly full.

Since I have 100 gigs of virtual mem the problem did not appear anymore.

Comment: The list is NOT "almost complete". Look at the scroll bar at the right. You're showing maybe an eighth of the processes on your machine. It is not a process "problem", you just need more RAM. Not pagefile space (what you are calling "virtual RAM" or "virtual memory") - you were never close to running out of that originally. RAM. You need more RAM.

Comment: "even with all processes stopped and only the most essential background running the memory was nearly full." Better post a screenshot of that, then. It is normal for processes' working sets to expand to use available RAM; if the processes don't want it, the OS will use the remainder for various types of cache. The cache is still counted in "available", however. It's very common for a Windows system to show no or very little "free" memory.